# Distinguish 1-bromobutane and 2-bromobutane with IR

Tags: ir-spectroscopy

How can I distinguish 1-bromobutane and 2-bromobutane by their IR spectrums?

In the 1-bromobutane spectrum I think the $\ce{-CH3}$ peak is shorter, but I don't know if that is actually reasonable or just a fluke.

In the spectrum that I think is 2-bromobutane there is an additional peak at around $1290$. What might this be?

The only alkyl halide peaks we discussed in class was the $\ce{C-Br}$ stretch $600-750$. They both seem to have this (although they do look different). How can I distinguish?

Comment: Meh, with NMR it would be crystal clear.

Comment: Sure would! Unfortunately this is an IR problem set.

Comment: From NIST database [1-bromobutane](https://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?ID=C109659&Units=SI&Type=IR-SPEC&Index=0#IR-SPEC) and [2-bromobutane](https://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?ID=C78762&Units=SI&Type=IR-SPEC&Index=0#IR-SPEC) in the gas phase.

Comment: I did see the different spectrum on SDBS, but I'm more interested in given just the two spectrum and the two compounds, how can you tell which goes with which?